# Using find with this returns undefined in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I am trying to loop through an element with class name and find the input value inside it:

```
 document.querySelectorAll('.qty').forEach(element=>{
        console.log($(this).find('input').val())
    })
```

This returns `undefined`

However, if I change the code above to:

```
 document.querySelectorAll('.qty').forEach(element=>{
        console.log($('.qty').find('input').val())
    })
```

Isn't `this` supposed to refrence the class name with quantity. Why does `this` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using an arrow function which does not contain its own `this` binding. Use an ordinary ES5 function:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".qty").forEach(function(element) {
  console.log($(this).find("input").val());
});
```

To make your code more concise, you could use jQuery's inbuilt functions, and discard the unused `element` parameter.

```
$(".qty").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).find("input").val());
});
```

Or forget about `this` and use the parameter, which would allow you to use an arrow function:

```
$(".qty").each((_, e) => console.log(e.find("input").val()));
```

Comment: Please close duplicates

Comment: My bad @adiga, I didn't know that a duplicate of this question existed, and I don't have a list of duplicate questions because I'm not too heavy on the dupehammer provided by a gold tag badge to require one.

Answer (score 1):

$(this) inside `forEach` is representing the the global window object. If you prefer to use jquery change it to `$('.qty').each` instead of using `querySelectorAll`

```js
$('.qty').each((i, v) => {
  console.log($(v).find('input').val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='qty'>
  <input type="text" value="1"></div>

<div class='qty'>
  <input type="text" value="1"></div>

<div class='qty'>
  <input type="text" value="1"></div>

<div class='qty'>
  <input type="text" value="1"></div>
```

Comment: Please close duplicates

Answer (score 0):

This in javascript behaves a little differently.  the value of this is determined by how a function is called (runtime binding).

For further explanation please refer to this documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this